# Having trouble with autoloading and namespaces , can someone spot what bugs me ?

Tags: php, mysql, class, namespaces, autoloader

I'm learning php/mysql at the moment, and i'm stuck following a tutorial. 
It's about AUtoloding, and namespaces.

My code looks like that : I'll sperate files by their name.

```
Folders : 
mysite/
   app/
      Autoloader.php
      Database.php
   pages/
      home.php
      single.php
      Template/
         default.php
   public/
      index.php
```

My code : 
/public/Index.php ============================================

```
    <?php
require '../app/Autoloader.php';
App\Autoloader::register();
if (isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $p = $_GET['p'];
} else {
    $p = 'home';
}
ob_start();
    if ($p === 'home') {
        require '../pages/home.php';
    } elseif ($p === 'single') {
        require '../pages/single.php';
    }
$content = ob_get_clean();
require '../pages/template/default.php';
```

/app/Autoloader.php ================================================

```
<?php
namespace App; 
class Autoloader
{
    static function register()
    {
        spl_autoload_register(array(__CLASS__, 'autoload'));
    }
    static function autoload($class_name)
    {
        if (strpos(__NAMESPACE__, '\\') === 0) {
            $class = str_replace(__NAMESPACE__, '\\', '', $class);
            $class = str_replace('\\', '', $class);
            require __DIR__.'/'.$class_name.'.php'; 
        }
    }
}
```

/app/Database.php ==============================================

```
<?php
namespace App;
use \PDO;

class Database
{
    private $db_name;
    private $db_user;
    private $db_pass;
    private $db_host;

    private $pdo;

    public function __construct($db_name, $db_user = 'root', $db_pass = 'password', $db_host = 'localhost')
    {
        $this->db_name = $db_name;
        $this->db_pass = $db_pass;
        $this->db_user = $db_user;
        $this->db_host = $db_host;
    }
    private function getPDO()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=blog;host=localhost', 'root', 'password');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $this->pdo = $pdo;

        return $pdo;
    }

    public function query($statement)
    {
        $req = $this->getPDO()->query($statement);

        $datas = $req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

        return $datas;
    }
}
```

MY Error message :

Fatal error: Class 'App\Database' not found in C:\wamp\www\Johan's Blog\pages\home.php on line 3

So i suppose its in the Autoloader that he can't require the Database.php. 
But i can't see where i go tsomething wrong. 
I don't really get that namespace thing.

If anyone has a clue ?

Thanks in advance :) 
Have a good day !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your error, we can see that your page `C:\wamp\www\Johan's Blog\pages\home.php` is trying to use the class 'App\Database'.

I think the problem is that your namespace path is relative here, seeking from the class located in the same path. You should try to use it with an absolute path, `\App\Database` instead of `App\Database`.

To understand well how namespaces are used and how it works, you should make simple scripts to teach yourself how it really work, because it is an important thing to understand. Try to read some tutorials dude, good luck with that :) !

Comment: Yes i had found out since then, fixed it exactly the way you said :)